# Unable to update ShopifyAPI::Collect object using Ruby script

Tags: ruby, shopify, collect

I am working on a shopify app in which I want to run a script which is in Ruby. I want to update the 'position' and 'sort_value' of  Collect object as per this link https://docs.shopify.com/api/collect. Everytime I try to do so I got an ActiveResource Error.

Here is my code in  irb:

```
require 'shopify'
require 'active_resource'

shop_url = "https://#{API_KEY}:{PASSWORD}@SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin"
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = shop_url
product = ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:id)
product.position = 4
product.save
```

I have tried the code given below, which works fine in irb

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(179761209)
product.handle = "burton-snowboard"
product.save
```

I got this error:

ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found

Can we send http PUT request on Collect object to update position? Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not providing any ID to your call.

product = ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(:id)

What is that supposed to return?

I think you have a 404 returned it is a good indication you are not asking for something with a valid ID. Your second call works fine with an ID.

Comment: when I run this code 
   ``product = ShopifyAPI::Collect.find(23423343)``
I got `ShopifyAPI::Collect` object.

But when I try to update this object i got `404` error.

Comment: No worries.. if you read the documentation for Collect, you'll see that you cannot even do what you are trying to do. So best you read the documentation and move on.

Comment: @David Lazar, You mean to say, we can't change the property 'position' in Collect. What if I want to change it? Is there any other way to do so? I wan to change the position of product in collection using `position` attribute.

Comment: I am not saying anything. Try a PUT maybe that works for existing resources. The docs and experiments are all I know